# Does Dart have an equivalent of TypeScript's --noImplicitAny, enforcing static typing unless explicitly disabled?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting to grips with Flutter and the Dart language, but keep occasionally making silly mistakes because the language lets me. In the [docs on type inference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart#type-inference), it says:

> The analyzer can infer types for fields, methods, local variables, and most generic type arguments. **When the analyzer doesn’t have enough information to infer a specific type, it uses the `dynamic` type.**

This seems to happen a fair amount, and there's no way to see what the analyzer was and wasn't able to infer. For example:

```
void doThings(List<int> integers) {
  print(integers);
}

main() {
  doThings([1, 2, 3].map((i) => i + 1));
}
```

There's no warning in the IDE (IntelliJ) or during compilation, but at runtime we get an ugly `TypeError: Instance of 'MappedListIterable<int, int>': type 'MappedListIterable<int, int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'` because I needed a `.toList()` call.

To catch mistakes like that at compile time instead of runtime, TypeScript has an option `--noImplicitAny` which makes any un-inferrable type into an error, rather than silently substituting a variant type (`dynamic` in Dart, `any` in TypeScript).

Is there a way to make the Dart compiler this helpful too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the static analyzer. You need to add `analysis_options.yaml` to your root.

To forbid implicit types use the following:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

More information: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: Marvellous! Red squigglies all over now :) I read about this "strong mode" but all the articles were pre-Dart 2.0 and I got the impression that it just got renamed to "sound Dart" or "the type checker" along the way.